# Json.NET and name/value array serialization

Tags: json, .net, serialization, json.net

Is there a way to serialize the attributes property below with a name/value property in .NET?  I can't seem to find a good way to serialize the class to the attributes property with values like, sport, venue, city, province, and others.

```
{
"uid": "uuid",
"object": "live_event",
"title": "Event Name",
"event_start": "2022-10-10T12:00:00:000Z",
"timezone": "America/Denver",
"external_id": "some_external_user_generated_id",
"container_uid": "02f8270a-8662-45b3-898a-c915a68cdf87",
"description": "Description of the event",
"short_description": "Short description of the event",
"attributes": [
{ "sport": "Soccer" },
{ "venue": "New Park" },
{ "city": "Calgary" },
{ "province": "Alberta" },
{ "teams": ["teamA", "teamB"] }
]
}
```

**Class**

```
     public class CreateEventRequest : VidFlexRequest, ISaveEventRequest
        {
            [JsonProperty("uid", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public string UId { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("title")]
            public string Title { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("event_start")]
            public string EventStart { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("timezone")]
            public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("external_id")]
            public string ExternalId { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("description", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public string Description { get; set; }
    
            [JsonProperty("short_description", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
        

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest ( but not the best)  way would be define your attributes property
as

```
    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public  Dictionary<string,object>[] Attributes { get; set; }
```

the better way is to use JsonConstructor

```
public class CreateEventRequest 
{
    [JsonProperty("uid", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string UId { get; set; }

    .....
   
    public  List <KeyValuePair<string,object>> Attributes { get; set; }
    
     [JsonConstructor]
    public CreateEventRequest(JArray attributes)
    {
        
    Attributes= attributes.Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, object>( 
         ((JObject)a).Properties().First().Name,((JObject)a).Properties().First().Value )).ToList();
    }

}
```